# What is the best solution for making mutli-language website, copy paste page ? script?

Tags: javascript, php, redirect, localization

I already done a website called Kinouk

Question 1)

French = https://www.kinouk.com/fr
English = https://www.kinouk.com

Each index page is checking if the user is new, if so we redirect him to the right index.php ( depending on their browser language and then set a cookie so next time he get on site he will get redirect ) and if the user click on french button ( top left ) when he is in english it change the cookie value to french so he will get to french version next time.

Is that good? I heard google do not like redirect pages

Question 2)

Anyone know a good file upload script + button for uploading Multiple files, scale pictures and create a thumbnail? I can only find single file upload script which isn't that "cool".

Comment: It might be more useful if you split your second question into a second question.

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1**

You can check if a cookie is set using PHP and it's nice `$_COOKIE` array, server side, and set the `header()` accordingly. This means there's no messy client-side redirect with a flash of half-loaded page.

**Question 2**

I'm suprised you haven't head about [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/). You'll need to scale the images server side using [GD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php), but there are nice classes for it [around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5162478/php-wrapper-class-for-gd) and [about](http://www.bin-co.com/php/scripts/classes/gd_image/) (more on [Google](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=php+gd+class&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:unofficial&client=firefox-a)).

Comment: Question 1: Yea , I do check the cookie and redirect before client side is ready but I was wondering if that solution was the best

Question 2: I tried that script but I couldn't make it work and when you go on modify your ad I need to show images that are already on his ad, can I do that with uploadify? It need to set some photo in that box when the page is loaded so the user can delete or ad new photos

Comment: Yes, that's fine - sending `header()`s and redirecting from the server is the best way to go. This way, the browser/search engine never really "sees" the intermediate page if it were done with JS.

Comment: ooh so search engine only see client side? oh and I changed comment number 1 if you could take a look :)

Comment: In response to your original comment, you'll need to try something yourself for Question 2. If I understand you correctly, you might want to look for `iframe file upload ajax` or something. And yes, search engines only see client side. Imagine the bother you'd be in if it could snoop around all the files on your server.

Comment: uploadify look ifne but an u add picture to the div conteainer dynamiclay

Comment: Probably, yes. You need to try something yourself, as well as doing some research, before posting more comments. Also, I'd recommend putting something in a new question as you're talking about Uploadify now instead of redirecting pages.

Answer (score 0):

### You're doing it wrong

Setting a cookie and redirecting when no cookie is present will mean your site is only visible to search engines in one/your default language - because in every request the search engine bot will be 'detected' as a new user and redirected.

It's also an annoying user experience to be forced to accept cookies (or edit accepted languages) just to be able to view a site in another language.

### Better approach

If the cookie is present, by all means redirect *on the first request of a visit* - but it should be an explicit action, or javascript which sets the cookie; not, effectively, any and all requests. It should still be possible to view the site in another language without jumping through hoops - i.e. If there is a 'view this page in french' link, *it needs to do what it says* for all users.